# Checking HTML within a meteor app

Tags: javascript, meteor, mixpanel

I am building a meteor app and using MixPanel for analytics, mixpanel offers extra points for their free plan by [adding their badge](https://mixpanel.com/free/) into your website, the problem is their autochecker can't detect the badge because of the client side rendering in meteor .

I still have content in the footer (where I am putting the badge) that needs to be dynamically manipulated, how can I manage to get the autochecker to see that the badge is already on the webpage ?

Comment: Look up server-side rendering in meteor.

Comment: The problem with this, I want to render the badge, but still need helpers and reactivity in that footer

Comment: That's great btw, [meteorhack's ssr](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/ssr) have template helpers on their server side templates, I think that can be modified to serve my needs, will give it a try

Comment: That won't work normally, as this is a partial layout, meaning that `footer` is actually `yield`ed into the main layout, any workaround to make that template rendered on the serverside then attach it to main layout ?

Comment: the question is should be: how does their autochecker check for this badge? it is likely if you include their script in the template that has the badge it will check at that time when it is rendered (as opposed to putting the script in the header or somewhere rendered outside of this scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. I just emailed their support, and got a reply within 1-2 days.

They had helped me added the extra stuff manually ... I guess they had no way to support this client side rendering stuff programmatically yet.

It's a bit annoying since I'll have quite a few apps to need to do this, but I guess for now I'll email them every single time, at least good to know they do get back soon and help you add it.

P.S. much better solution than hacking with server side blah or whatever else hack... programmers tend to think like this first haha

Comment: That's what I did anyways, was hacky enough to do the server side rendering for a partial view